# Persistent connection between GWT and Android client (or App Engine inbetween)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, sockets, gwt, websocket

What I'm trying to achieve is a connection between a users browser (logged in with his Google account) and an Android application on his phone (also logged in with the same Google account). I want to send a bunch of text formatted as JSON from GWT to the device and the other way round too.

My first thought was to send a C2DM ping to the Android devices and wake up a service witch connects to the App Engine server or the GWT client directly (if that's possible).

What I'm doing now is a socket with the Channel API from GWT to App Engine. And for a large amount of text I would just send a notification via the Channel to the GWT client, which then gets the data with a RPCall. Missing is the connection between the App Engine and the Android application. What I could do is C2DM for one direction and simple HTTP requests for the other direction. I don't like this solution, because C2DM can be really slow some times.    Is there a solution to connect these two (GAE & Android app), or even a better without App Engine and a connection between the GWT client and the Android client directly ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: C2DM sounds correct to me. Is there a reason it won't work for you?

Comment: But sometimes C2DM can take a few minutes until the phone receives the ping. What I want is kinda a chat between the GWT and the Android client where I send text in both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to *push* messages from a server (in your case `GAE`) to an Android app *without* using C2DM? In that case you can give [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) a try.

Edit: of course you have a few options in this area (another one being [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications)) but you'll notice that they're not cheap!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a connection between GWT and Android directly" -- do you mean a connection between a GWT *client* and an Android phone? If so, there's not a good way to do that without installing client software; you'll need some sort of server to proxy messages.

So, given that you're using App Engine and GWT already, and C2DM is potentially too slow, you could wrap up an HTML page on the Android and use the Channel API. Then when you get messages, have your javascript client (again, running on Android) call the container to do anything you want.

This is nice because you have parity in the message delivery between your browser clients and your Android clients. It's not nice because it's not native and probably will eat battery, unlike C2DM.

Ideally I know you'd like a native API for Android to consume Channel API messages. You can vote for this issue but I unfortunately can't provide an ETA for it: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4189

Comment: No, I'm not saying that I want a connection between them without an Android application. I'm writing a GWT client, an App Engine Server and an Android application. The Android application has to be native. I'm going to edit the question a little, so that it's clearer